How to configure authorization and authentication using both credential and OAuth approaches?
I have a fairly common problem, or at least I thought it was before I started looking for a solution. I want to create a perfect boilerplate for how authorization and authentication should work. I’ve been trying to implement this in a Next.js app for the frontend and Node.js (Express) for the backend. It works, but the two parts are somewhat separate from each other. Next.js provides a lot of built-in features for authentication, but when it comes to authorization, working with tokens, and handling both cases simultaneously, it’s not so straightforward. I would like to store my users in a database and control their permissions based on their roles.
Is there an efficient way to handle both (for example, Google Auth and credential-based authentication), have a role management system, and manage it all together? Perhaps someone has some code examples or repositories?
